# I need IP addresses of LinkedIn

Tags: networking, mobile, ip, linkedin-api

i have been directed by LinkedIn to this developer's blog. I want to give access to LinkedIn for certain users on a mobile network. This is why i would like first to know if they are static or dynamic, and if there is a predefined list which someone can share.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: to access linkedin you don't need IP address, do you try something else?

Answer (score 7):

LinkedIn has a total of 6 AS Numbers:

- AS13443
- AS14413
- AS40793
- AS55163
- AS197612
- AS197613

For your ease, I have created a git repo with all the ipv4 and ipv6 ip addresses of LinkedIn, Facebook and Twitter. Please find them from the links below:

```
https://github.com/aarvee11/LinkedInIPLists

https://github.com/aarvee11/TwitterIPLists

https://github.com/aarvee11/FacebookIPLists
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find a range of ips belonging to linkedin but it's not listed as ASN owner.

Here is an example of the case:

```
ASN AS10912 - Internap Holding LLC
Hostname    No Hostname
Range   63.251.192.0/19
Company LinkedIn Corporation
```

I suggest using CIDR instead. Here ara more accurate ips of linkedin

```
8.22.121.0/24
63.251.195.64/29
64.124.192.64/29
66.151.157.240/29
91.225.248.0/22
108.174.0.0/20
144.2.0.0/19
144.2.176.0/20
144.2.192.0/19
144.2.224.0/21
144.2.232.0/22
144.2.236.3/32
144.2.236.4/30
144.2.236.8/29
144.2.236.16/28
144.2.236.32/27
144.2.236.64/26
144.2.236.131/32
144.2.236.132/30
144.2.236.136/29
144.2.236.144/28
144.2.236.160/27
144.2.236.192/26
144.2.237.3/32
144.2.237.4/30
144.2.237.8/29
144.2.237.16/28
144.2.237.32/27
144.2.237.64/27
144.2.237.96/28
144.2.237.112/29
144.2.237.120/30
144.2.237.124/31
144.2.237.127/32
144.2.237.131/32
144.2.237.132/30
144.2.237.136/29
144.2.237.144/28
144.2.237.160/27
144.2.237.192/26
144.2.238.0/23
185.63.144.0/22
199.101.160.0/22
202.177.212.160/29
204.51.86.192/27
216.52.16.0/21
216.52.242.0/24
216.200.149.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you cannot allow access the domain name?  E.g. `www.linkedin.com` (Or whatever domain the api is)

But, if you'd like to get the ip of a domain, you could use the ping command on windows cmd or linux/maxos bash, the output will be different depending on your system, but it should contain the numbered ip.

```
ping www.linkedin.com
```

Comment: Yes. Technically we would have to feed the list of IP addresses of that domain into the system

Comment: for example, IP in OpenVPN config.